# How to make a Xamarin app fullscreen (all screen)

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, fullscreen

I develop with Xamarin 4.5 and I'm not able to find how to put my application to cover the entire screen (full screen).

For Android and for iOS.

Note: I do not want only an image or a video to cover the entire screen, it should be all the application that should cover the entire screen.

**Update 2020-04-29**
I found half of the solution, only the Android part (inlcluded in my answer with help of FabriBertani for status bar). I tested it and it works fine. Now I have to find a solution for iPhone (or at least, find a way to test on an iPhone).

Answer (score 8):

On Android add this to the `OnCreate` method of your MainActivity:

```
this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
```

For iOS add these values to the `info.plist` file:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

**edit**: If you want to remove the toolbar too just add this on your xaml pages:

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
```

Or in the C# code behind

```
public YourPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
}
```

If you want to add this to all your pages, I recommend you to create a base page with this and then use this base page in all your pages.

```
public class BaseContentPage : ContentPage
{
    public BaseContentPage
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    }
}
```

And use it on the xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<local:BaseContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace.Pages"
    x:Class="YourNamespace.Pages.YourPage">
</local:BaseContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! Sounds good an Android , but I still have the navigation buttons on the bottom on the emulator (perhaps normal). Let me a week or so just to check on real devices to see the results (I'm new to Xamarin). Thanks a lot for the moment. I do not forget you and will mark as the good answer after testing if everything is as expected.

Comment: Thanks FabriBertani, I wasn't able to remove navigation buttons. I thought it was because I was in Master-Detail project. I created another one with a simple page project. (I also had to re-install VS2019 because my emulator stopped working). But still, the navaigation is still visible all the time???

Comment: My code (includes some tests-try): http://www.ericouellet.com/dl/alarmclockez.zip

Comment: By the way... The Navigation buttons are the one that are parts of Android (3 buttons: trinagle, circle and the square). Ican't find how to remove that bar???

Answer (score 5):

This is half of the solution. For Android:

In Android Project. Into MainActivity.OnCreate, add:

```
this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen); // Hide StatusBar, from FabriBertani

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "HideOsNavigationBar", (sender) => 
{
  int uiOptions = (int)Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;
  uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
  Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility) SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
});
```

In Shared project. Into MainPage constructor (I put it after InitializeComponent() but I doubt it is necessary):

```
MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this, "HideOsNavigationBar");
```

Comment: Hi , glad find the solution ! Remember to mark it when you can :-)

Comment: When I will find a way to test  it with iOS and make sure it works, I will mark the proper answer as the good one. :-)

Comment: Great ,that's fine. If find a solution in iOS ,  will also share here latrer .